# How do I get the current cell number whilst looping through a range of cells (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get the current cell number whilst looping through a range of cells.

```
For Each i In Sheet3.Range("A3:A213")

  msgbox(Sheet3.Range("B"&currentcellnumberinloop).Value)

Next
```

The purpose of this is to retrieve a value from another cell in the same row e.g. A1 and B1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `i` is probably declared as Range object(*or Variant*). Therefore to get the row number and retrieve the value in neighboring `B` column you have to call the `.Row` method of the `i` object

```
Sub ForEachAndFor()

    Dim i As Range

    For Each i In Sheet3.Range("A3:A213")
        MsgBox Sheet3.Range("B" & i.Row).Value
    Next

End Sub
```

You could also use the `Offset(how_many_rows_up_or_down, how_many_columns_left_or_right)`

you indicate rows down with a positive number an rows up with a negative number

same applies to the columns, use `-` to navigate to the left of the current cell, and positive number to the right of the current cell.

```
Sub ForEachSub()

    Dim i as Range

    For Each i in Sheet3.Range("A3:A213")
        MsgBox i.Offset(0, 1).Value
    next i 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim i as Integer

    For Each i In Sheet3.Range("A3:D213").Rows.Count
     msgbox(Sheet3.Range("B" & i).Value)
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code variable i is of a Range type, thus you have to treat it that way. You can use Offset to get to what is in relation to your i address, like that:

```
For Each i In Sheet3.Range("A3:A213")

  MsgBox (i.Offset(0, 1).Value)

Next i
```